Can I remove react-native-gesture-handler safely after I dropt react navigation from my react native project?
I used to use react navigation in my react native project but after we moved everything to a webview wrapper instead of native elements, we are not using react navigation in any way, two of the libraries that depends of react navigation are

react-native-gesture-handler
react-native-screens

Running depcheck gives these two as unused packages, so my question is:

Should i keep these two after removing react-navigation, or they are still relevant somewhere?

I removed the two libraries and everything seems to be working fine but am still not sure what are the consequences of this change?
